# Time Machine Back Up

Tags: backup

I am really sorry for this type of question, but can you please explain to me in a better way the statement below so I can understand better the type of back up that TIME MACHINE does. Thank you

"Time Machine keeps hourly backups for the past 24 hours, daily backups for the past month, and weekly backups until your backup drive is full."

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't really a good fit for SO (which is for development and programming questions); however, Apple has a good [video](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#timemachinebasics)on the basics of Time Machine. It really is as simple as you've described it: Time Machine will take a backup each hour and keep that backup for a day. Then it'll keep one backup from that day for a month, and one backup from each week for as long as possible.

The backups are "deltas", meaning only changed data is backed up, which helps keep backup sizes small and therefore maximise the amount of backups you can keep.

[This site](http://pondini.org/TM/Home.html)also has a wealth of hints and tips about Time Machine.